# How to Design System for Resonating Tuning Forks from Base

Tags: vibration, audio-engineering

I have seen [videos like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yia8spG8OmA) where two tuning forks with matched frequencies are attached to resonant chambers and the sound from one fork can be used to resonate the other fork.

I am interested in building a system where a tuning fork can be resonated automatically using a transducer vibrating the chamber at a matched frequency.

My initial prototype hasn't been successful, but it seems like this should work on the same principle of sympathetic vibration.

I build a wooden base and bolted in a tuning fork. I am using a surface mount transducer playing a matched sine wave from a signal generator through a class D amplifier. So far I have not been able to get the fork to move or vibrate.

What factors should I be looking at to get this to work?

Here's a picture of my setup:

[image]

Comment: replace the transducer with a tuning fork and test

Comment: In the video, **the presenter strikes both tuning forks one after the other**. Thgat doesn't match your description "*and the sound from one fork can be used to resonate the other fork*"

Comment: @AJN if you watch the whole thing he strikes both to demonstrate them resonating by themselves, then uses one to resonate the other

Comment: @jsotola that is a good thought! that could better isolate whether it's an issue with the wooden structure or the method itself